# Limiting the dark area during popup in angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

The pop up works flawless with bootstrap. Now I'm trying to limit the dark area during popup, I don't want the header to be covered in dark during popup, some thing like this[image]

Comment: If the gap is static, may be you could override style of the dark overlay with your own css rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure out the z-index of the backdrop, make the header's z-index 1 higher. Currently Bootstrap's modal backdrop is set to a z-index of 1040. So try something like this...

```
<header class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="z-index: 1041;">
    ...
</header>
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/VX6sEjiSnVzg07MRIZen?p=preview)